# Launch newly-installed application from Mac .pkg with non-admin privileges

Tags: macos, pkgbuild, productbuild

I'm building a Mac installer package (.pkg) using pkgbuild and productbuild. I'm able to get my application bundle installed, but I'd like to launch it at the end of the install. I added

```
open /Applications/MyAppName
```

to the postinstall script. This launches my app, but it has different permissions or otherwise differs from an app that the user manually launches after completing the install. The installer requires admin privileges since it's copying the app bundle to /Applications, but this appears to interfere with the functionality of the app when launched by the postinstall script. One example is that an applescript command in my app that's supposed to copy a file with admin privileges fails.

Is there some way to launch an app with the user's normal privileges?

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
sudo -u "$USER" open /Applications/MyAppName
```

This will run your application as specified user.